# jquery find .html() equal to val();

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have an ajax form and I need to locate the 5 digit zip entered. -- val();

```
var zip = ($("#edit-field-zip-value").val());
```

After submit, results are loaded in a table with upto 10 zips.  Within the 10 zips, one needs to be identified with jquery.

```
$(".zip div:html[text=zip]").addClass("equal");
```

The above line is obviously incorrect. Can someone help out with here. If it isn't possible with my line of jquery, I am open to another more flexible solution.

ex:

```
if (zip == tablezip) {
  console.log("hello"); 
}
```

MARKUP:

```
<td>
  <div class="zip">
   <div>90042</div>
   <div>90052</div>
   <div>90062</div>
   <div>90072</div>
   <div>90082</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct jQuery would be, using [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('.zip div:contains('+zip+')').addClass('equal');
```

If you needed it to be exact, you could do:

```
$('.zip div').filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() == zip;
}).addClass('equal');
```

Comment: Thanks Guys! both work but I failed to post my html code. :\ Please see my updated question html

Comment: Appologies, Paolo, your second suggestion did the trick. I failed to try it before posting the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the div that contains the zip?  Try the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```
$(".zip div:contains("+zip+")").addClass("equal");
```