# Jquery remove divs not equal to search results

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, filter

Original question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541905/jquery-find-html-equal-to-val)
Upon searching i need to alter the results across rows which are equal to the search val();

For this example lets assume we need 90042.

Current js:

```
(function($) {

            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
                var zip = ($("#edit-field-zip-value").val());

                $('.zip div').filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text() == zip;
                 }).css('color','red');

            });

        }(jQuery));
```

Markup:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="zip">
       <div style="color: red">90042</div>
       <div>90052</div>
       <div>90062</div>
       <div>90072</div>
       <div>90082</div>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
     <div class="marker">
      <div>foo</div>
     </div>
    </td>

    <td>
     <div class="dma">
      <div>Pheonix</div>
      <div>Flagstaff</div>
      <div>Tucson</div>
      <div>Lipsum</div>
      <div>Goro</div>
     </div>   
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

The end goal here is to remove all div's other than 90042, foo, and pheonix.

Something like this:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="zip">
       <div style="color: red">90042</div>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
     <div class="marker">
      <div>foo</div>
     </div>
    </td>

    <td>
     <div class="dma">
      <div>Pheonix</div>
     </div>   
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

I have a feeling the results of my questions will result in un-even rows so it may be necessary to append end results to new divs or table. ( Might be wrong here tho )

Comment: Can you modify the markup? It seems like you're working with a table of data, and this would be easier if you could just remove table rows that don't have a value in a certain cell matching your query.

Comment: @DonZacharias, sure thing. Let me know if i need to manipulate the markup any more. This is a drupal 6 view table so its not very flexible as far as manipulation but I can always move away from tables  if you think it would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with your answer to @DonZacharias' comment, you could format the HTML this way

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="zip">90042</td>
    <td class="marker">foo</td>
    <td class="dma">Pheonix</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="zip">90043</td>
    <td class="marker">foo</td>
    <td class="dma">Arizona</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and then the code becomes

```
var zip = 90042;
$('td.zip').not(function() { return $(this).text() == zip; }).parents('tr').remove();
```

otherwise you have to find the index of the div you're looking for. It ain't a good idea, but if you insist, this should do it:

```
var zip = 90042;
var index = -1;
$('.zip div').each(function(i,el) { if ($(el).text() == zip) { index = i; return false; } });
if (index != -1) {
    $('.zip, .dma, .marker').each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).find('div').not(':eq('+index+')').remove(); 
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for assistance. Can you comment on why you wouldn't recommend finding the the index of the div? For completeness, i am going with the 2nd script because i am not seeing a simple way to manipulate the table.

Comment: it's most probably slower and prone to errors: specifically the way I scripted it, it would break if you had `<div/>`s inside `<div/>`s, needs adjusting if you change class names, and that's just for starters. You should format you data to a structure that most fits your needs, and if there are three linked items which should be displayed as one row - a `<table/>`'s only logical. What problems would you have to manipulate a table? The code I gave was a single-liner...

Answer (score -1):

here's a code to remove all div's other than what you have indicated.

```
$("td > div > div").not(":first-child").remove();
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/puUf7/).

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: he asked to remove non-hits, not the first rows.

Comment: @Yuval oh, my bad, I must have misread what he wanted. anyway, thanks for pointing that out, I'll be sure to read questions carefully next time.